# Session validation filter which logs off the user when session is expired

Tags: java, servlets, authentication, servlet-filters

I have a session validation Filter which logs off the user when session is expired.

Here is a piece of code but this is not working. Not working means this is not redirecting to the login page even if the session expires.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;  
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;  

    HttpSession s = req.getSession(false);  

    if (s==null)
    {
        //redirect to login page with session expiry message   
    } else {  
        chain.doFilter(request, response);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: have you checked sesion id in redirect block? is it changing? Is it possible that your soft/framework calls getSession(true) somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *I have a session validation Filter which logs off the user when session is expired.*

This makes honestly no utter sense. If you store the logged-in user as an attribute of the session and intercept the "logged-in" status based on the presence of the logged-in user in the session, then you do not need to manually logout the user at all when the session is expired. When the session expires, all its attribtues will get lost anyway and hence the user will be "automagically" logged out.

Here's an example of how you can login the user in the `doPost()` of a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which is invoked by a POST submit of the login form [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info).

```java
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
User user = userService.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user); // Login user.
    response.sendRedirect("userhome"); // Redirect to user home page.
} else {
    request.setAttribute("errormessage", "Unknown login, try again"); // Set error message.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response); // Redisplay login form.
}
```

You see, when the login is valid, the user is stored as a session attribute. The remnant of your code could just check if it is null or not to determine if the user is logged in. Whenever the session expires, it automatically becomes null.

---

> *this is not redirecting to the login page , even if the session expires*

I have no idea what you're trying to do since the initial functional requirement makes no sense. However, there exist two common functional requirements related to session expiration and the login page. I guess that you *actually* need either one of them:

1. *"How do I redirect the visitor to the login page when he requests a page which is restricted to logged-in users?"*

   You need to create a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) and map it on the (common) URL pattern of the restricted page(s). In the filter, just check if the user is present in session and then continue the chain, else redirect to login page.

   ```java
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
       HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
       HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

       if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
           response.sendRedirect("login"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
       } else {
           chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
       }
   }
   ```

   ---
2. *"How do I automatically redirect the currently opened page to the login page when the session expires?"*

   Use the `<meta>` refresh in combination with [`HttpSession#getMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29).

   ```html
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};url=sessionexpired.jsp">
   ```

   This will automatically redirect the current page to the given `url` whenever the session expires. The `${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}` expression will inline the session expiration time in seconds, which is exactly what the `content` attribute needs.

Comment: I have <meta> tag but it just redirects to the page I've specified instantly.

Comment: @Makky: Apparently it printed `0`.

Comment: OK. Could you guide me how do I redirect automatically when session expires ?

Comment: @BalusC: Great answer but just out of curiosity what is the reason of not using getSession(false) for tracking session. It is clearly written in the docs that it returns null when there is no existing session attached to the request.

Comment: @unknown: because you want the container to create one anyway. Do note that the filter doesn't do that because you don't want the container to unnecessarily create it even when you're not going to make any use of it.

Comment: @BalusC - "If you store the logged-in user as an attribute of the session" The question never said the logged in user was a session attribute though.

Comment: @david: that's exactly why there's an "if". On the other hand, if OP used container managed authentication or a decent 3rd party authentication framework, the entire question was been unnecessary. It's therefore more likely that the OP is manually managing authentication and that's usually to be done by setting the logged-in user as a session attribute.