# The browser shouldn't allow me to go worked page after click the back button when logged out (always shows login.jsp) page

Tags: java, jsp

I used the code given below but it still not working

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, 
max-age=0, private");; 
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Edit: Adding jsp tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for session on the server side - a typical way would be to use a filter which redirect to your login page if no session is available.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370885/session-validation-filter-which-logs-off-the-user-when-session-is-expired) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set those response headers on all JSPs for which you would like to disable the browser cache, not only on the logout page or something.

You normally use a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this so that you don't need to copypaste the same piece of code over all JSPs. Here's how the filter could look like, assuming that all your restricted pages share the same URL pattern of for example `/app/*`:

```
@WebFilter("/app/*")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code on logout page will solve the problem.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
javascript:window.history.forward(1);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you are code will disable the back button,I need the button which shouldn't be disable in the same time it shouldn't go to worked page ,it means still remain in login page