# Redirecting HTML page only once

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, jsp

I have Spring app that uses JSP. And I need to redirect one page, but only once. It's due the spring security - once the user comes to this page, I need to call redirection to log him out, but to stay on the same page. Is there any way, how to do this only via java, html or js? Or maybe I've asked wrong - there must be some way, how to do this, but I'm not very into frontend technologies, so I'd be glad, if anybody could post some code to show me, how to make this work.. Thanks :)

So the usecase: user types mywebsite.com/login -> I need to call redirect to log him out in the case he's already logged -> the same site shall appear but now without redirection.

PS: I can't redirect the user to another site - it must be the same site with same source code.

Comment: You're looking for `session.invalidate();` at Java server side in your controller request handler. When finishing, do not redirect to other page. It would be better if you post [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) in order to get better help.

Comment: Related: [Session validation filter which logs off the user when session is expired](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7370885/1065197), check section two of the accepted answer (nearly the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case, I would rather log out a user as a part of the login action (i.e. factor out the logging out process, and call it from both the logout action, as well as from the login action).

If that is not feasible (and I can't of a reason why it wouldn't be), I would focus on "redirect if he's logged in" part rather than "redirect only once" part - the former is very easy to check without almost any modification to your code, assuming you're using some kind of sessions to track the logged-in status.

Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about Sprint, these are all very general comments that should work on any classic webapp.

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter .

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest test1=    (HttpServletRequest) arg0;

         test1.getRequestURL()); it gives  http://localhost:8081/applicationName/menu/index.action
         test1.getRequestURI()); it gives applicationName/menu/index.action
         String pathname = test1.getServletPath()); it gives //menu/index.action


        if(pathname.equals("//menu/index.action")){ 
            arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1); // call to urs servlet or frameowrk managed controller method


            // in resposne 
           HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
           RequestDispatcher rd = arg0.getRequestDispatcher("another.jsp");  redirect to another page at response time 
           rd.forward(arg0, arg1);





    }
```

donot forget to put  `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` in filter mapping in web.xml
If you do not want to use filter you can redirect to another jsp from urs controller method.

Comment: A `Filter` is not the right place to do this job (nor any similar component).

Comment: If you do not want to use filter you can redirect to another jsp from urs controller method.

Comment: Refer to [this great answer and explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371899/1065197) to understand why your approach is wrong.

Comment: That's a reason to make this post a non answer at all.

Comment: Then use sessionlistener .Call listener and use counter to track it.When counter value >1 show errorpage.jsp.